# How should I go about avoiding sql injections?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a query:

```
@results = the_db.where('name LIKE ?', '%#{input}%').paginate(
    :page => params[:page], 
    :per_page => 50, 
    :group => "name", 
    :order => [
        "CASE WHEN name like '#{input}%' THEN 0 
        WHEN name like '% %#{input}% %' THEN 1
            END, name"
    ]
)
```

The problem is that this is vulnerable to injections. (The order clause) How do I solve this problem? Is it possible to somehow sanitize the user's input to negate any attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sanitize_sql_array` method.  Unfortunately, it is a private method, so you have to call it with `send`.

```
query = <<-QUERY
CASE WHEN name like ? THEN 0 
     WHEN name like ? THEN 1
     END, name
QUERY

sanitized_order = ActiveRecord::Base.send :sanitize_sql_array, [query, "'#{input}%'", "'% %#{input}% %'"]

@results = the_db.where('name LIKE ?', '%#{input}%').paginate(
:page => params[:page], 
:per_page => 50, 
:group => "name", 
:order => sanitized_order)
```

Comment: I get an error: `can't find string "QUERY" anywhere before EOF`

Comment: Ah, yeah, you have to terminate the multiline string.  I left that off.  Sorry about that.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use parametrized queries.

```
@results = the_db.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{input}%").paginate(
    :page => params[:page], 
    :per_page => 50, 
    :group => "name", 
    :order => [
        "CASE WHEN name like ? THEN 0 
        WHEN name like ? THEN 1
            END, name",
            '#{input}%',
            '% %#{input}% %'
    ]
)
```

Although I'm not sure how it behaves if you have `%` in the strings.

Comment: i have similar code running on one of my websites. i can vouch that this works with % %.

Comment: The parameters aren't getting filled in o.O It's just there at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`sanitize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize) method on your `input` string before or after embedding it.  This is essentially what Rails parameterization does for you.

Be aware that sanitizing will add a leading and trailing single quote `'`, that you can remove if needed using the following:

```
sanitize(something)[1..-2]
```

In your example, you can do:

```
:order => [
    "CASE WHEN name like #{sanitize "#{input}%")} THEN 0 
    WHEN name like #{sanitize "% %#{input}% %")} THEN 1
        END, name"
]
```

Note that you will need to call `sanitize` within a class method or scope, or use a namespace that has access to it (e.g. `ModelName.sanitize` or `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also tryout squeel gem:

https://github.com/ernie/squeel

Rian Bates, in his RailsCasts, gives a nice introduction to squeel:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel?view=asciicast